# Getting all items in the collection mapWithKeys

Tags: laravel

I have:

```
$collection=Event::all();
$keyed = $collection->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
                return ['title' => $item['name'], 'start' => $item['event_date']];
   });
```

`$keyed->all()` is returning only last item in the collection with changed keys:

```
Array
(
    [title] => New Year
    [start] => 2018-01-01
)
```

How do i get all events with changed keys?

Comment: What do you get if you put `dd($collection->toArray());` after `$collection=Event::all();`?

Comment: @whoacowboy `dd($collection->toArray());` gives `array:3 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Parent's Day"
    "event_date" => "2018-02-14"
    ]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "Labour's Day\n"
    "event_date" => "2018-05-01"
    ]
  2 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "name" => "New Year"
    "event_date" => "2018-01-01"
    ]
]` while `dd($keyed->toArray());` gives only the last event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback of **mapWithKeys** return an associative array conaining  a single key / value pair, so if you just need **name** and **event_date** I suggest to use pluck like this:

```
$collection=Event::pluck('event_date', 'name');
```

Comment: i need `title` and `start` as array keys instead of `name` and `event_date` attributes.

Comment: $array = Event::select('name as title', 'event_date as start')->pluck('name', 'start');